# Noob has multiple android problems

Tags: android, arrays, string, button, onclicklistener

So, I've never touched Java programming in my life (did a little C and C++, don't remember anything), but I'm trying to figure things out. I'm trying to make an Android app to display a random string from an array when a button is clicked. So far, I've been copying fragments from here and there. But I'm running into a problem with the OnClickListener.

```
package com.example.testrun01;

import java.util.Random;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private String[] PhraseString;
    private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Button btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClick);

    btnClick.setonclickListener(new onClickListner(){
        public void onclick()
{  
    PhraseString = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Phrases); 
    String q = PhraseString[rgenerator.nextInt(PhraseString.length)];
    tv.setText(q);
}
        });     

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Let me break down the Errors (4 in total):
1) The method setonclickListener(new onClickListner(){}) is undefined for the type Button
2) onClickListener cannot be resolved to a type
3) Cannot refer to a non-final variable tv inside an inner class defined in a different method
4) Syntax Error

The first two are on the same line, btnClick.setonclickListener(new onClickListner(){.
The third is at tv.setText(q);
The fourth is at });

I'm guessing resolution of the first three will resolve the fourth. If anyone out there is willing to help someone who has no knowledge of Java and is still attempting to write a program, please let me know where I went wrong and how to make sure I don't go wrong in the future. Thanking everyone in advance.

Comment: Short answer: capitalization and spelling matter.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that 5:30 AM is not the best time to dive into Java with no prior knowledge... Thank you for helping me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Button btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClick);

    btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListner() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            PhraseString = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Phrases); 
            String q = PhraseString[rgenerator.nextInt(PhraseString.length)];
            tv.setText(q);
        }

    });
}
```

Remember to check capitalisation and missed letters.

1. The method is `setOnClickListener` not `setonclicklistener`.
2. The listener interface is `OnClickListener` not `onClickListener`.
3. You need to define the TextView as final, `final TextView tv`, because it is accessed inside an annoymous class.
4. The method `onCreate` does not have the correct opening and closing braces. Put an extra `}` after the `});` to close the method body.

If you are using eclipse, you can do `CTRL` + `Space` which will provide you with some auto-complete options, which can help with capitalisation and spelling.

Comment: Still getting errors 1, 2 and 4... I checked my capitalization and made sure I didn't miss any letters... I've been seeing a lot of questions with the same problem, but they all seemed to have gotten resolved whereas mine has not... Am I missing an import or something?

Comment: It looks like you do have the correct imports though... if you're using an IDE (Eclipse for example) does it provide any automatic fixes if you "mouse-over" the line of code?

Comment: I am using Eclipse, and it's not... K-Ballo and you helped me with the first 3 errors... Not sure where the 4th is stuck...

Comment: I've figured it out, you forgot to close the braces for the method `onCreate`. Try adding another closing brace after the `});`.

Comment: Tried that... Still getting the error

Comment: I can't see anything else wrong after that fix, I've updated my code to include the entire `onCreate` block.

Comment: Or, I'm an idiot who doesn't save.. Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> 1) The method setonclickListener(new onClickListner(){}) is undefined for the type Button

Yes, it is. The method you are looking for is called `setOnClickListener`.

> 2) onClickListener cannot be resolved to a type

The type you are looking for is `OnClickListener`. Not only you wrote a lowercase `o`, you missed an `e` as well.

> 3) Cannot refer to a non-final variable tv inside an inner class defined in a different method

That's just the way *Java* works. If you want to access say `tv` inside your anonymous `OnClickListener` then declare `final TextView tv`.

> 4) Syntax Error

The method for `OnClickListener` is supposed to be called `onClick`.

Comment: Thanks! It seems I did miss that "e"... Now am left with error 4...

Comment: You haven't closed the `onCreate() {` method. Add one `}` on the line after `});`. Using proper indentation will help you visualize when you forget to close something like this. :)

Comment: Go it, thanks. I need to pay more attention. And, y'know, learn Java...